# Show ony positive axis ColumnChart Google

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I read now this tutorial fo developers:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Using object **hAxis** and parametr *direction* i try to show only positive axis of my chart.
Also i wanna, that my axis be only **integer numbers**, now it is *0.5, 1, 1.5*
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vAxis: {viewWindowMode: "explicit", viewWindow:{ min: 0 }}

Comment: Doesn't seem to work anymore, even if it's in the docs, it has no effect

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper  set vAxis.minValue = 'positive integer' . that worked for me .  check this  https://codepen.io/serenemathew47/pen/eYZVxze

Answer (score 1):

The `direction` option only controls the direction of the axis (left-to-right, or right-to-left), not what values are shown.  Use the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and `hAxis.viewWindow.max` options to control the range of values displayed on the axis.  Setting `hAxis.viewWindow.min` to `0` will prevent any negative numbers from showing up.

Keep in mind that the columns are centered on their axis values, so if you have any columns at 0, you have to give them a bit of space to the left of 0 to draw all of the columns.  Similarly, they need a bit of space to the right of the max value to fit all of the columns.

By default, the ColumnChart will try to place 5 axis tick marks (which you can change by setting the `hAxis.gridlines.count` option), evenly spaced throughout your data.  This can end up with some rather odd results.  Sometimes you end up with decimals in the labels that can be safely ignored (this is especially true when your axis spans a large numeric distance); in this case, you can set the `hAxis.format` option to drop decimals (eg, `'#,###'`).  If your data spans a smaller range, you might be better served specifying the `hAxis.ticks` option, which takes an array of values to place tick marks at.